# WPF Toolkit Charts - Points doesnt reset when changing data in collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, charts, wpftoolkit

In my program I use MVVM Light Toolkit.
I have a window with a TabControl consisting of 4 tab items.
Then I have a UserControl which have a Chart from WPF Toolkit (it has its own ViewModel). This UserControl is used in 2 of the tabs.

The ObservableCollection, which holds the data for the chart is Cleared and new Items are added to it when the user press a Button. This updates the chart fine if im in the tab with the chart. If I update the data more than 1 time in a row without looking at the tab with the chart, the data points from previous updates remains.

Anyone have experience with updating a chart when you're not in the "View" which is updated?

EDIT:
Basically it's this code in XAML:

```
<charting:Chart  Margin="-20,-30,0,-20" Name="TimeChart" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"
     Panel.ZIndex="2" Visibility="{Binding Path=TimeChartVisibility}" >
        <charting:Chart.Axes>

            <charting:DateTimeAxis Orientation="X" Interval="Auto" AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource RotatedAxesLabelStyle}">
                <charting:DateTimeAxis.Title>
                    <Label Content=""></Label>
                </charting:DateTimeAxis.Title>
            </charting:DateTimeAxis>

            <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="True" Minimum="-5" Maximum="105" >
                <charting:LinearAxis.Title>
                    <Label Content=""></Label>
                </charting:LinearAxis.Title>
            </charting:LinearAxis>

        </charting:Chart.Axes>

        <charting:LineSeries  Name="OffSerie"  DependentValuePath="PerformanceValue" IndependentValuePath="Time" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PerformanceReadings}"
              IsSelectionEnabled="True" Title="" DataPointStyle="{StaticResource DataPointBlue}" />

        <!--remove legend from chart-->
        <charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
            <Style TargetType="datavis:Legend">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </charting:Chart.LegendStyle>

    </charting:Chart>
```

I have an ObservableCollection bound as Itemssource.

How the graph should show:
[image]

How it shows in 2nd tab:
[image]

Comment: Could you show us some code?